# Why won't my Canon 6D RAW file import into Photoshop CS5.1 after installing Camera Raw?

Tags: canon, raw, canon-6d, adobe-camera-raw

I have installed Adobe Camera Raw on my computer, but I cannot open a RAW file in CS5.1 Extended from a Canon 6D.

What am I missing?

Error message:

> Could not complete your request because the file appears to be from a camera model which is not supported by the installed version of Camera Raw. Please visit the Camera Raw help documentation for additional information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Canon 6D was added to Camera Raw 7.3, which requires CS6. I think your only options are to use the DNG converter, upgrade Photoshop, or switch to another tool like Lightroom.